# SQL Server Select With Loop on second table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am struggling with some SQL logic and wondered if you can help?

I need to get a list of **ID's** from table **"Roles"** where **emailEnabled is true**, I then need to use these IDs against the table **"Users"** on the **roleid column** to grab their email addresses and **return** these as a **comma separated list**.

I know we need to use a loop in here but it's not my strong point.

Let me know if you need any further info.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not recommend generating a comma seperated list in SQL. Grab the data you need record-wise and handle the rest in your program logic.

You can get the data you need like this

```
select users.email
from users
join roles on roles.id = users.roleid
where roles.emailEnabled = 1
```

Comment: Agreed, classic case of me trying to get to deep instead of keeping it simple :-) Will mark as accepted as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in SQL although I'd probably advise against it;

```
DECLARE @tmp varchar(100)
SET @tmp = ''
SELECT @tmp = COALESCE(@tmp + ',','') + (SELECT u.emailAddress FROM Roles r LEFT JOIN Users u ON r.roleid = u.roleid WHERE r.emailEnabled = 'true')

SELECT @tmp =  RIGHT(@tmp,LEN(@tmp)-1)
```